# Can I board without my infant child even though I'm marked as passenger with baby in the reservation?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, children

I have booked a return flight with Turkish airlines for my family (myself, my wife, one 6-year-old kid and another infant, 10 months old), and we used the outbound trip.

Now for the return, my wife got some problem with paperwork and cannot make the return flight. So we've decided that she will stay (with my parents, it's our hometown actually) until the visa is done, and **she will stay with the younger child** (the older one has to go back to school and I have to go back to work, and each of us cannot accompany both).

When I when to booking management to cancel this return trip online for my wife, I could do that just fine. But I noticed that for the smaller child I cannot do anything with her reservation, i.e. I can't cancel her ticket, because she's attached to me! (I'm marked as passenger with a baby -- either I cancel mine and she will share the same effect, or she will stay in the PNR no matter what).

So the question is, when I arrive at the airport to do the check-in, can I just check in myself and the older kid? I don't want the scenario where they issue all 3 boarding passes for 3 people, then my small one is no-show at the gate, or can it be even worse: I might be denied boarding as they can ask 'where is the baby you're supposed to carry with you'?

(If I try to check in online it will show "check in for 2 people". My infant child has a ticket number of her own too).

Comment: Did you talk to the airline?

Comment: Almost impossible to chat with an agent online, they redirect you to a whatsapp channel where there's a chatbot with very limited option. In my current city they don't have a call center. I will try to find some way to call today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You will be fine to travel**: the baby will simply be marked as a no-show, same as if an adult traveller in the group does not show up.

If your wife was still planning to travel with the baby on her ticket, she would have a problem, because the baby would no longer have a ticket after "no-showing".  But you said she cancelled her ticket entirely, so this won't be a problem either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I however don't understand the second part: "because the baby will no longer have a ticket"?

Comment: @JimRaynor Clarified the wording a bit, but if the baby no-shows to their flight (with you), their ticket will be cancelled and your wife would be unable to fly with them.  But this is all hypothetical, since your wife is buying a new ticket anyway.

Comment: I confirm this answer. I boarded without problem. To be sure, I called the call center of Turkish airline they confirm it's fine. At the check-in desk, I simply don't put the passport of the baby, and they ask "so the baby won't be travelling?" and that's all. A boarding pass was still got printed out as I can see, but the staff tore it down rightaway.

Comment: @JimRaynor Glad this worked for you! Please tap the ✔️ to make this answer as accepted.